# What is the state of user-based audio submissions?

Tags: html, flash, audio, encoding

Does anyone know what the state-of-the-art is in user audio submissions? I know about WAMI recorder but I was just wondering what a high profile website would do. For instance, if a site like soundcloud wanted to do user-based audio submissions, how would they do it? Considerations are encoding on the client or server and which encoding, flash or html5 or both, mobile, compatibility, microphone access etc...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Roundware - it may be helpful: http://www.roundware.org/